# 3D pointcloud to 2d costmap layer projection github repo

Tags: navigation, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I remember stumbling upon a Github repository which had a costmap layer which basically projects a 3d pointcloud or 3d sensor data (don't quite remember) down to a 2d plane / costmap layer.

I can't find it even anymore (been looking for 30 mins now ._.).

Anybody knows the name of the repo or could give me a link?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231595/3d-pointcloud-to-2d-costmap-layer-projection-github-repo/) by [AReimann](https://answers.ros.org/users/20356/areimann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2016-04-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

here is an example:

```
  plugins:
    - name: pc_layer
    type: 'costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer'

  pc_layer:
    enabled: true
    observation_sources: rgbd_cloud
    combination_method: 1 

    rgbd_cloud:
      sensor_frame: base_footprint
      data_type: PointCloud2
      topic: cloud 
      expected_update_rate: 1.0
      observation_persistence: 0.0
      marking: true
      clearing: true
      raytrace_range: 4.0
      obstacle_range: 2.5
```

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2016-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AReimann](https://answers.ros.org/users/20356/areimann/) on 2016-04-25**:
Yeah found it myself. I was really wondering why I thought the normal obstacle layer does not do that ~_~